# Default Cordova index.html is compiling

Tags: android, html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have cordova latest version installed on my system and I created the basic app with command

```
cordova create
```

and I added the platform using

```
cordova add platform android
```

and I replaced the default **index.html** in the **www** directory with **my own index.html**

but whenever i tried to generate apk, and tried to run it on my mobile. **It was the apk generate with default index.html**

the screen of my app will be

[image: App with Default index.html even with my own index.html]

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: in your Cordova app directory, where is located the www folder containing the index.html you edited ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour.

Cordova is going to take the `index.html` from your projects root folder, everytime you run `cordova build`, `prepare` or `serve` without attribues, which is located directly inside your projects `www` folder.

Root `www` folder inside your cordova project contains the `index.html` which is taken and "*thrown*" into all platform folders when you run those commands.

`projectName` -> `www` -> `index.html`

---

**Solution**

1. You work in your projects root folder, and run `cordova prepare` everytime after you did a change to your `index.html` file.
2. You work directly inside your android project folder and the `index.html` which is located inside the `assets` -> `www` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can change default index.html file to your own .html file
Simply open config.xml file in your project folder and edit its src attribute in `<content>` tag:
like:

default: 
    content src="index.html"

edited:
    content src="helloCounterApp.html"
    (Then it will load helloCounterApp.html not index.html(default))